# CHECK/NOCHECK for Sql Compact Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-ce

I am attempting to wipe and repopulate test data on SQL CE.  I am getting an error due to FK constraints existing.  Typically in Sql2005 I would

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] CHECK/NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

to enable/disable all constraints.  From what I could find in my searching, it seems that this might not be supported in CE.  Is that true?  If so, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NOCHECK is not supported on SQL CE 3.1/3.5

[ALTER TABLE SQL CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123(v=sql.100).aspx)

The usual method to accomplish this is to drop the constraint, do your operations and then add it back.

Comment: FYI, NOCHECK is not available in CE 4.0, either:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123.aspx